# General algorithm to securely serialize objects

Tags: serialization, cryptography

I need to serialize a (*possibly complex* *) object so that I can calculate the object's `MAC`**.

If your messages are strings you can simply do `tag := MAC(key, string)` and with very high probability if `s1 != s2` then `MAC(key, s1) != MAC(key, s2)`, moreover it is computationally hard to find `s1,s2` such that `MAC(k,s1) == MAC(k,s2)`.

Now my question is, what happens if instead of strings you need do `MAC` a very complex object that can contain arrays of objects and nested objects:

**JSON**
Initially I though that just using JSON serialization could do the trick but it turns out that JSON serializers do not care about order so for example: `{b:2,a:1}` can be serialized to both `{"b":2,"a":1}` or `{"a":2,"b":1}`.

**URL Params**
You can convert the object to a list of url query params after sorting the keys, so for example `{c:1,b:2}` can be serialized to `b=2&c=1`. The problem is that as the object gets more complex the serialization becomes difficult to understand. Example: `{c:1, b:{d:2}}`
1. First we serialize the nested object:`{c:1, b:{d=2}}`
2. Then url encode the `=` sign: `{c:1, b:{d%3D2}}`
3. Final serialization is: `b=d%3D2&c=1`

As you can see, the serialization quickly becomes unreadable and though I have not proved it yet I also have the feeling that it is not very secure (i.e. it is possible to find two messages that `MAC` to the same value)

Can anyone show me a good secure*** algorithm for serializing objects?

[*]: The object can have nested objects and nested arrays of objects. No circular references allowed. Example:
`{a:'a', b:'b', c:{d:{e:{f:[1,2,3,4,5]}}, g:[{h:'h'},{i:'i'}]}}`

[**]: This `MAC` will then be sent over the wire. I cannot know what languages/frameworks are supported by the servers so language specific solutions like Java Object Serialization are not possible.

[***]: Secure in this context means that given messages `a`,`b`:  `serialize(a) = serialize(b)` implies that `a = b`

**EDIT**: I just found out about the SignedObject through [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076237/learn-java/signed-and-sealed-objects-deliver-secure-serialized-content.html) link. Is there a language agnostic equivalent?

Comment: If you want an unqiue serialization to calculate MACs, why do you care if it´s readability is good? (And no, you can´t calulate MACs from Strings, only if you specify a charset too)

Comment: And, if the MAC algo works fine and secure for strings, why shouldn´t it work for strings with a specific content (JSON etc.) ?

Comment: @deviantfan you are right, readability is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **canonical representation**, either for the data storage itself, or for pre-processing before applying the MAC algorithm. One rather known format is the canonicalization used for XML-signature. It seems like the draft 2.0 version of XML signature is also including HMAC. Be warned that creating a secure verification of XML signatures is fraught with dangers - don't let yourself be tricked into trusting the signed document itself.

As for JSON, there seems to be a canonical JSON draft, but I cannot see the status of it or if there are any compliant implementations. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4670494/589259) is a Q/A where the same issue comes up (for hashing instead of a MAC). So there does not seem to be a fully standardized way of doing it.

In binary there's ASN.1 DER encoding, but you may not want to go into that as it is highly complex.

---

Of course you can always define your own binary or textual representation, as long as there is *one* representation for data sets that are semantically identical. In the case of an textual representation, you will still need to define a specific character encoding (UTF-8 is recommended) to convert the representation to bytes, as HMAC takes binary input only.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It seems weird that there is no 'standard' way of doing it given that this must be a fairly common problem.

Comment: Andy: "The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from."